# how to search a particular song using search button

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread

i am unable to search a perticular song by usng search button from the long list of songs after its been upgraded to android 2.3.5.  Before that i was able to find a song using search button.i am using htc desire s handset.

Please suggest if there is a solution to this.coz if i need to listen a perticular song ,i have to traverse through all the library and fing the song after 15 -20 minutes..

Answer (score 4):

You have to add Music to the **Searchable items** in the *Search settings*.

These settings you normally find when pressing the phone's **Search button** (to view the Search widget) -> [Menu] -> **Search settings** -> **Searchable items** and you select the items you want to include in your search.

On a **HTC phone** I think you find these settings here:
[Menu] (while on a Home screen) -> **Settings** -> **Search** -> **Searchable items**.